# With Apache Flink, how can i intersperce a stream so values are emitted on empty windows

Tags: apache-flink

I am aggregating data over one hour windows. When no event within one hour has arrived, the agggregating function is not called, and the zero aggregation is never calculated. My output therefore misses entries for the windows that are emtpy. Is there an easy way to make sure the empty windows also are calculated in order for me to be able to emit the zero aggregations?

```
Events          ->   A - - B - C - - - - - - E - F -
Desired output  ->   [     2][    1][     0][     2]
Observed pr now ->   [     2][    1]        [     2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, Flink does not support empty windows. Internally, there has to be at least one element belonging to a window in order to create it.